# NSMutableString appendString generates SIGABRT Error

Tags: iphone, xcode

New here (this forum and Xcode in general), so bear with me.

I've spent multiple hours off and on over the last severals days trying to track down what exactly that I'm doing wrong here, but I just don't seem to be able to pinpoint my issue.

Here's the relevant sections of my code (I believe).

In the header:

```
@interface BlahViewController : UIViewController {

  NSMutableString *display;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *display;
```

In the main:

```
@implementation BlahViewController

@synthesize display;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.display = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];  
}

- (void)anotherFunction:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *info = [[sender titleLabel] text];

    [self.display appendString:info];
}
```

I run the code, press the UIButton, and I get an error. Here's the initial throw:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM appendString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e3d300' ***
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The whole stack trace was requested, so here it is (after reviewing the stack I realize there may be confusion, I'm writing a very basic calculator currently, so the ViewController, etc, should consider that backdrop and "anotherFunction" = "digitPressed" in this particular case):

*** Call stack at first throw:
(

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e345a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f88313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>
>     2   CoreFoundation                      0x00e360bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
>
>     3   CoreFoundation                      0x00da5966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00da5522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>     5   Calculator                          0x0000273b -[CalculatorViewController digitPressed:] + 113
>     6   UIKit                               0x002bb4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
>     7   UIKit                               0x0034b799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>     8   UIKit                               0x0034dc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
>     9   UIKit                               0x0034c7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
>     10  UIKit                               0x002dfded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
>     11  UIKit                               0x002c0c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
>     12  UIKit                               0x002c5f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
>     13  GraphicsServices                    0x01723992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>     14  CoreFoundation                      0x00e15944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
>     15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d75cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>     16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d72f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
>     17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d72840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d72761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>     19  GraphicsServices                    0x017221c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
>     20  GraphicsServices                    0x01722289 GSEventRun + 115
>     21  UIKit                               0x002c9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     22  Calculator                          0x00002254 main + 102
>     23  Calculator                          0x000021e5 start + 53
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
>   Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: The 'self.display = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];' line is a memory leak. You should instead use
`self.display = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];`
or
`self.display = [NSMutableString string];`

Comment: Is it a memory leak if I release it in my viewDidUnload method? Because the way it's arranged now is that the -viewDidLoad alloc/inits and the -viewDidUnload releases.

Comment: 'display' is a property with _retain_ memory management. So when you do `self.display = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` it is strictly equivalent to `[display release]; display = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] retain];` and you have a retain count of 2.
If you have `self.display = nil` in you viewDidUnload method, you're decreasing the retain count by one, so there is still some memory allocated for the string but no way to access it anymore. It's a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayM appendString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4e3d300' ***

This indicates that you are calling `appendString:` an instance of some kind of `NSArray`, which obviously won't work.

Assuming that `[self.display appendString:info];` is the actual source of the exception, then it is happening because `self.display` has likely been over-released and, coincidentally, an `NSArray` instance was allocated at the same place in memory.

You could use zombie detection to debug this.

Alternatively, you might be corrupting memory somewhere.  Or, maybe, there is another assignment to `display`.

In any case, whenever you have a crash, there will be a backtrace.  Please post it.  There is the off chance that the crash is happening somewhere else.

---

```
5 Calculator 0x0000273b -[CalculatorViewController digitPressed:] + 113
```

Show the source to your `digitPressed:` method.

---

```
self.display = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

That is a memory leak;  it'll be retained twice.  Just do `self.display = [NSMutableString string];` and `self.display = nil;` (in your `viewDidUnload`).

But that isn't the source of your problem;  something is resetting the `display` variable *or* it is being over-released.   Show all uses of `display`.

Comment: The error is occurring at the line you indicated. The stack trace is provided in the edits.

Comment: Try changing the name of the NSMutableString and see if that helps.

Comment: Why would changing the name of the mutable string help?!  The error message is clear as to what is happening and the backtrace shows that it is going off the rails in `digitPressed:`.

Comment: Not sure if you caught it bbum, but the "digitPressed" method is actually the method in question here. 

anotherFunction = digitPressed.

Comment: Nope -- didn't catch that.  Not sure why anyone would think a rename is going to help when execution is clearly crashing on that one line [as the backtrace indicates].

Comment: .... I just caught it, I can't believe I didn't notice this before. It was in one of the loops, I was reassigning it to an NSMutableArray. Purely by accident. Wow. How did I not notice that. 

Well, thanks for your impervious logic bbum. It's incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Glad you found the problem!  When relatively new, it is easy to fall in the trap of randomly changing stuff in hopes that it fixes the problem.  One of the challenges is learning to sift through the oft massive amount of spew / evidence related to a crash to find the signal that identifies the actual problem.  It takes practice.